# Import data from Excel through Silverlight application

Tags: c#, excel, silverlight, import

I am trying to create a utility to import all data from a excel sheet and update Sharepoint list through Silverlight application.

I have got the file details using openfiledialog method. Below is the code.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Multiselect = false;
    dlg.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    dlg.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

    // Show dialog               
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        // Get the selected file name and set it as text of a TextBox
        FileInfo fInfo= dlg.File;
        txtfilename.Text = fInfo.FullName.ToString();

        FileStream Stream = dlg.File.OpenRead();
```

After this, I am trying to read the data from the sheet and fill the list using the below C# code

```
Workbook book = Workbook.Open(Stream);
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
for (int i = sheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex; i < sheet.Cells.LastRowIndex; i++)
{
  for (int j = sheet.Cells.FirstColIndex; j < sheet.Cells.LastColIndex; j++)
    {
       //CODE TO ADD ITEM IN THE LIST 
    }
}
```

But now problem is, the methods Workbook and Worksheet are not recognized in my code as there is no reference. What is the equivalent assembly reference for these methods in the Silverlight application? In a normal C# app, we use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll for these methods.

I am using Silverlight 5.

Comment: Could some please help me on these?

Comment: I used Spreadsheetgear dll to import the data from excel. Below is the code

Answer (score 0):

I used Spreadsheetgear dll and below is the code.

```
Workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(fInfo.FullName);    
worksheet = Workbook.Worksheets["sheet1"];    
cells = worksheet.Cells;
```